# Smoothing a circle - painter drawing

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter

I am using the following code to draw an image in a circle.

```
 QPixmap target(110, 130); // the size may vary
    target.fill(Qt::transparent);

    QPixmap p = QPixmap::fromImage( QImage(":/Images/head").scaled(110,110,Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio,Qt::SmoothTransformation).convertToFormat(QImage::Format_ARGB32));
    QPainter painter(&target);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);

    QRegion r(QRect(10,10,100,100), QRegion::Ellipse);
    painter.setClipRegion(r);

    painter.drawPixmap(0, 0,p);

    ui->label->setPixmap(target);
```

This is the output that I get

[image]

Notice the circle is not smooth. My question is how could i make this circle smooth.

Comment: FYI, there is no difference between `painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);` and `painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);`.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up

Comment: You can use QPainterPath instead QRegion. QPainterPath p; p.addEllipse(QRect(10,10,100,100)); painter.setClipPath(p);

Answer (score 3):

Using clip path will not has antialias ability in drawing.

You can use a mask image or make a color mask image to draw image to a special shape that.

Here is a simple example:

```
        QPainter *painter....
        QPixmap pixmapToDraw....
        ....
        QImage dst(sourceRect.width(), sourceRect.height(), QImage::Format_ARGB32);
        dst.fill(QColor(0, 0, 0, 0));

        QPainter p(&dst);
        QPainterPath path;
        path.addRoundedRect(0, 0, sourceRect.width(), sourceRect.height(), sourceRect.width() / 2, sourceRect.height() / 2);

        p.setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing | QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform, true);
        p.fillPath(path, QBrush(Qt::white));
        p.setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_SourceAtop);
        p.drawPixmap(dst.rect(), pixmapToDraw);
        painter->drawImage(0, 0, dst);
```

Here is Qt's doc [Image Composition Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-painting-imagecomposition-example.html), [QPainter::CompositionMode](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#CompositionMode-enum)